# Save html5 data attribute value in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have link like this

```
<a href="#" data-quantity="1" class="buynow">Buy now </a>
```

data-quantity value is assigned when the user select product quantity.

As of now I getting data-quantity value like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $(document).on( 'click', '.buynow', function() { 
        var quantity = $(this).attr('data-quantity');
    });
});
```

The code works fine at first, but if the user changes the quantity again, then it displays the previously used value.

Can some tell me how to refresh the value?

Thanks

Update:

My quantity select button looks like this

```
<div class="quantity buttons_added">
<input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
<input type="number" step="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text">
<input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
</div>
```

Comment: How are changing the quantity, please include the code for this. If you debug is the data tag being changed on product change?

Comment: The posted code looks fine, so the issue is probably how the data attribute is updated, and using jQuery's `data()` won't really update the attribute, so I'm guessing wildly that's the issue.

Comment: Tip: read initial state from the HTML (i.e. from your `data-*` attributes), but then forget about the HTML. The in-memory representation of the data should be treated as the truth - this saves you from the headache of keeping them in sync, and is faster and easier to manipulate than the DOM. It's a good pattern to follow in nearly all circumstances

Answer (score 0):

You need some code to change the data tag

```
$('.minus').click(function(){
  var qty = $('.buynow').data('quantity');
  if(qty!=0)
    $('.buynow').data('quantity', qty - 1);
})
$('.plus').click(function(){
  $('.buynow').data('quantity', $('.buynow').data('quantity') + 1);
})
```

Not tested

Comment: Hi when I change the product quantity, my data-quantity value also changes. Which is correct.. My problem is this. First time I select 3 product and added to the cart. It echoes "3 products has been added to the cart". But if I select 5 products again, I can see the data-quantity value changes correctly. But If I press Buy now button, I get the same message instead of "5 products has been added to the cart".. Do you think your code solves that issue?

Comment: Your code above does not effect the data-quantity tag, could you please post all code which when you click the plus or minus buttons makes change to the data-quantity.